# CRUD: using mat-Dialog as UI

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material, dialog, crud

I'm having a list of a playlist using mat-card and I'm getting my data from an array list inside my `PlaylistComponent`

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to add another playlist that's why I added a new playlist button that will display a dialog

[image]

I've added a playlist service that contained my form group.

My problem is that I'm new and I got lost with the architecture of the program. 
do I have to use two-way binding or do I have to find a way to implement it in my dialog component

if someone is familiar with this technique please give me an insight.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking.  Is the problem getting data back from your dialog?  Is the problem getting data from the form?

Comment: I'm sorry for being not clear :). my problem is how to add data from a form that exist in a Dialog to a an array that exists in another component

Answer (score 1):

Your question is asking a lot and you don't give the underlying code so I am going to give an outline and point you to the documentation to follow for your specific implementation.

Basically you take the data from the form and pass it in `mat-dialog-close`.  When you open the dialog from your playlist component you also subscribe to the `afterClosed` of the dialog.  In this subscribe, you will get the data back from the `mat-dialog-close`.  You then can push that data into your existing array.

The first example of `mat-dialog` in the documentation handles a form and returning the data [Dialog | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding my request even though it was very lacking. This is exactly what I was looking for :)